# testing reactive form with custom async validator returning observable

Tags: angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

Could someone please show to to test reactive form that has async validator returning an observable. I want to test that form control that has this async validator is invalid and has expected error when async validator returns observable with non-null value.

In my test form control is valid and has no errors even though form validation is working correctly in my application. When I debug my unit test I can see that async validator returns correct value but I can't figure out how to test validation error.

thank you